# PrintPreviewDialog jumps to last page shown

Tags: c#, .net, print-preview

I have a Windows Forms app in C# and am using a PrintPreviewDialog. My multipage document shows each page correctly and from within the dialog, I can click the page number selector in the top right to change the page I am viewing.

Now when I close this dialog without printing, and try to run the same dialog again on the same set of data, the dialog opens back up already displaying the last page number I was on when I closed it.

Question: How can I cause the print preview dialog to show the first page upon opening so the user doesn't have to manually roll it back to page 1?

Specific Details:
System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewDialog was dragged from tools onto the form in design view.
Using Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
.NET Framework version 4.6.01586

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help. I am a student and only started learning C# four weeks ago and .NET 9 weeks ago, but have been programming in other forms of Basic for  over 30 years.

Comment: That happens when you use the same PrintPreviewDIalog object repeatedly. A likely outcome when you use the designer.  Add printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.StartPage = 0; before the ShowDialog() call to ensure it always starts at the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works. Before assigning the document to my PrintPreviewDialog object, I create a new one and reference it using the old variable:

`ppdPrinter = new PrintPreviewDialog();`

Where ppdPrinter was the name of the control created in design view. I don't like that it has to create a new instance of the Print Preview Dialog to work, but I'll mark my own question as answered for anyone else's benefit.

I've tried disposing of the object, setting the document to null before assigning it, and looking through the document.PrintSettings for any options and this was the best I could come up with.

I'll welcome any solution that doesn't create a new PPD object with each print job.